# MongoDB Selecting very bad index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm running MongoDB version 2.6.7.  I have a collection with about 7 million documents in it.  Each document has a guid field on it which is unique.  Here is an example query which I expect should use the guid index but instead uses some crazy set of queries on a different index:

```
2015-02-02T23:05:13.349+0000 [conn6716672] query MyDB.persistentObject query: 
{ query: 
{ guid: { $in: [ "some_guid" ] }, 
ownerId: { $in: [ 0, 1, 1025252577, 994090559, 1317724, 1088410057, 
1125454113, 1122731922, 994089725, 1122732678, 1317394, 1129549288,1122731600, 
1312755, 1115032827, 1122461088, 1315404, 1025251224, 1124535620, 1059802590, 
1124023810, 1125620352, 991434980, 1115022865, 1115031571, 1124514149, 
1124534953, 1124534178, 1126176542, 1124533461, 149095604, 810047314, 
1069908537 ] } }, 
orderby: { updated: -1 }, 
planSummary: IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 },
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 },
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 }, 
IXSCAN { ownerId: 1.0, updated: -1.0 } 
ntoreturn:500 ntoskip:0 nscanned:6739394 nscannedObjects:6739394 
keyUpdates:0 numYields:7434 locks(micros) r:374790754 nreturned:1 reslen:55 274222ms
```

Here is the list of indexes on that collection:

```
shard1:PRIMARY> db.MyDB.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "MyDB.persistentObject"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "updated" : -1
        },
        "name" : "id_updated_index",
        "ns" : "MyDB.persistentObject",
        "dropDups" : false,
        "sparse" : false
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "guid" : 1
        },
        "name" : "guid",
        "ns" : "MyDB.persistentObject",
        "dropDups" : false,
        "sparse" : false
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "ownerId" : 1,
            "updated" : -1
        },
        "name" : "ownerId_1_updated_-1",
        "ns" : "MyDB.persistentObject"
    }
]
```

Since there is only one guid requested, but many ownerIds, I would expect the guid index to be used.  If it were used, it would result in `nscanned=1` and a very quick result. Instead, a very wasteful index is chosen.  This bad index gets selected over and over again on different queries, and the mongo instance becomes totally crippled.

db.stats():

```
{
    "db" : "MyDB",
    "collections" : 7,
    "objects" : 6761839,
    "avgObjSize" : 496.46051968998376,
    "dataSize" : 3356986104,
    "storageSize" : 3918581760,
    "numExtents" : 28,
    "indexes" : 14,
    "indexSize" : 983450160,
    "fileSize" : 10666115072,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 10,
        "totalSize" : 475508736
        },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

db.serverStatus().mem:

```
{
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 946,
    "virtual" : 38232,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 18409,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 36818
}
```

An example explain plan which correctly chooses the guid.  Most of the time, when I run explain, it does what I want.  But then something seems to happen once a day where it starts picking the bad index and we end up in a death spiral.

```
db.persistentObject.find({ guid: { $in: [ "some_guid" ] }, ownerId: { $in: [ 0, 1, 1025252577, 994090559, 1317724, 1088410057, 1125454113, 1122731922, 994089725, 
1122732678, 1317394, 1129549288,1122731600, 1312755, 1115032827, 1122461088, 1315404, 1025251224, 1124535620, 1059802590, 1124023810, 1125620352, 991434980, 1115022865, 
1115031571, 1124514149, 1124534953, 1124534178, 1126176542, 1124533461, 149095604, 810047314, 1069908537 ]}, orderby: { updated: -1 }}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor guid",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 20,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "guid" : [
            [
                "some_guid",
                "some_guid"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "myServer:27018",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "works" : 3,
        "yields" : 1,
        "unyields" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 0,
        "needTime" : 1,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "children" : [
            {
                "type" : "FETCH",
                "works" : 2,
                "yields" : 1,
                "unyields" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 0,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0,
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "type" : "IXSCAN",
                        "works" : 2,
                        "yields" : 1,
                        "unyields" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 1,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "keyPattern" : "{ guid: 1 }",
                        "isMultiKey" : 0,
                        "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['guid']: [\"some_guid\", \"some_guid\"]",
                        "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                        "matchTested" : 0,
                        "keysExamined" : 1,
                        "children" : [ ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you run the query in the mongo shell using explain()? can you add the output to the question?

Comment: Sure, but interestingly, the explain usually chooses the correct index (guid) as it did when I ran the query a few minutes ago.  I pulled the usage of the bad index from mongo logs last night, for an identical query.

Comment: mongo does periodically execute the query using each of the available indexes to see which one is most performant. It then selects this one to use for future matching queries. See link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#query-plan-revision. Would something have changed in your nightly processing to trigger a new query plan and potentially the wrong index to be selected as optimal?

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  But I don't know what it could be.  Maybe there is some edge case where that other index actually performs well, and that case happens at just the right time and ends up getting selected as the query plan?  It seems odd that this happens about once per day though, and we are then stuck with badly performing queries until I restart the mongod.

Comment: Can you post an `explain(true)`, just so I can see a little more information about how the plans compare to each other? How often do you write to this collection? It should reevaluate the query plan every 1000 writes, or when other, usually much rarer conditions are met. You might find it useful to read about [the query planner](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/) too. As far as I can tell right now this is truly the query planner being a dunce so maybe you should consider using `hint()`. Try 3.0 when it comes out :D

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have picked the index ownerId_1_updated_-1 as the best candidate for the query as this can help with the sort part of the query. This will still result in scanning a large amount of documents because it has to match the guid field.

try adding the guid field to the ownerId_1_updated_-1 index

```
 {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "guid" : 1,
            "ownerId" : 1,
            "updated" : -1
        },
        "name" : "guid_1_ownerId_1_updated_-1",
        "ns" : "MyDB.persistentObject"
    }
```

Comment: I get that, and sure I could add another index, but that's another 500MB that needs to sit in RAM to get a performant query in this very specific use case, when there is already an index in RAM that would perform well.  Doesn't mongo have some learning mechanism where it executes queries in several different ways to find the most efficient?

Comment: It can only use 1 index to satisfy the query and it is using the other index because it covers two parts of the query - select and sort.  you can try and pass a hint to force it to use the index you want. Is this the only type of query run on this collection?

Comment: No there are many queries possible, which generally follow the form: "Find me all objects which match this interesting field, within this set of ownerIds, sorted by most recently updated."  So you can see why it would be frustrating for me to make custom indexes on every one of those interesting fields in combination with ownerId and updated.  Indexing on the interesting field alone would give great performance if only the index were used.